# How to translate regular PHP form code to swiftmailer code

Tags: php, forms, validation, echo, swiftmailer

As a PHP-Newbie I need help with the translation of my regular PHP Code to deliver a html form. I partly understand the documentation given by swiftmailer. I had some problems with the regular mail () code, so I need to switch to swiftmailer. That's what I already coded. I need a validation of required fields and a link to a confirmation site if the form is submitted correctly.

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
->setUsername('')
->setPassword('')
;

$to = "test@test.com";
$from = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = "SUPPORT";

$fields = array();
$fields{"name"} = "Name";
$fields{"email"} = "Email";
$fields{"message"} = "Message";

$body = "Message:\n\n"; 
foreach($fields as $a => $b){   
$body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); 
}

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
->setSubject($subject)
->setFrom(array($from => $name))
->setTo($to)
->setBody($body);

$mailer->send($message);
?>
```

Comment: You don't tell us what's wrong with this code

Comment: Sorry, the code won't deliver mails, I get a server timeout error message, so the smtp is not working. Also I don't know how to validate my required html5 fields and I don't know how to link to a confirmation site if the form is submitted, or an error site if the form isn't correctly.